# JavaScript structuredClone got `Illegal invocation` in Chrome/Edge, but not in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, structured-clone

Run the following code in a browser:

```js
({ clone: structuredClone }).clone(1);
```

will got `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`, tested in Chrome/Edge.

However running the code in NodeJS is fine, tested in NodeJS v20.

Workaround:

```js
({ clone: (v) => structuredClone(v) }).clone(1);
```

Or

```js
({ clone: function(v) { return structuredClone(v)} }).clone(1);
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: alternatively - `({ clone: structuredClone.bind(globalThis) })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems platform specific.
If you run in Firefox you get a more descriptive error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: 'structuredClone' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.
```

So `structuredClone` in a browser needs to be executed in the `window` context. In a browser you can have multiple windows (iframes) acting as a global context opposed to Node where you have only one. So `structuredClone` should know which window to act upon.

```js
structuredClone.call(window, 1);

// hmm, works with null too, seems takes the current window
structuredClone.call(null, 1);

structuredClone.call(1, 1);
```

To solve the problem you could bind the function:

```js
({ clone: structuredClone.bind(null) }).clone(1);
```